# Injecting A Factory Into A Class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory

I'm developing an application feature for generating some sorts of strings. I have an interface:

```
interface IStringGenerator
{
    string GenerateNext();
}
```

and for now I have implemented this interface in a class having a single constructor with one parameter:

```
class FixedLengthStringGenerator : IStringGenerator
{
    // The class needs some dependencies, but I ignored them here to keep it simple
    public FixedLengthStringGenerator(int length /*and dependencies*/)
    { . . . }

    public string GenerateNext()
    { . . . }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

This implementation only generates the desired strings of a fixed given length `length`. `GenerateNext()` on each call returns a desired string, until there are no one left and then it returns `null`. Considering these, I need another implementation of `IStringGenerator` which can generate strings of length between a minimum and a maximum. I think it's natural to have something like this:

```
class MinMaxLengthStringGenerator : IStringGenerator
{
    int _MinLength;
    int _MaxLength;
    int _Length;
    IStringGenerator _StringGenerator;

    public MinMaxLengthStringGenerator(int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        _MinLength = minLength;
        _MaxLength = maxLength;

        _Length = minLength;
        _StringGenerator = new FixedLengthStringGenerator(_Length);
    }

    public string GenerateNext()
    {
        if(_Length > _MaxLength)
            return null;

        string generatedString = _StringGenerator.GenerateNext();

        if(generatedString == null)
        {
            _Length++;
            if(_Length <= _MaxLength)
            {
                _StringGenerator = new FixedLengthStringGenerator(_Length);
                return _StringGenerator.GenerateNext();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return generatedString;
    }
}
```

But creating instances directly is not a good idea. Instead I can use a factory to get an instance of `FixedLengthStringGenerator`. But I still think it's not a good practice, because it depends on `FixedLengthStringGenerator`. And if I want to use another alternative class in the future, this way it's not possible to receive it from outside.

My question is whether it's right (from the patterns point of view) to inject a factory into my `MinMaxLengthStringGenerator` or not?

More precisely, consider

```
interface IFixedLengthStringGeneratorFactory
{
    FixedLengthStringGenerator Create(int length);
}
```

Should I declare `MinMaxLengthStringGenerator`'s constructor like following?

```
public MinMaxLengthStringGenerator(int minLength, int maxLength, IFixedLengthStringGeneratorFactory factory)
{ . . . }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're very close.  Consider a factory that implements this interface:

```
interface IStringGeneratorFactory
{
    IStringGenerator CreateFixedLengthStringGenerator(int length);

    IStringGenerator CreateMinMaxLengthStringGenerator(int minLength, int maxLength, IStringGeneratorFactory factory);

    /* other types? */
}
```

Your assignments to `_StringGenerator`  within `MinMaxLengthStringGenerator` then become this:

```
_StringGenerator = _stringGeneratorFactory.CreateFixedLengthStringGenerator(_Length);
```

This removes references to your concrete implementation of `FixedLengthStringGenerator` from `MinMaxLengthStringGenerator`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ajeet-kumar makes a good point: if you can avoid variable type parameters in your constructors (like length, minLength, maxLength) by providing them on the method, by all means do so.  Then you can just rely on your classes to be constructed via your DI chain.  The above is appropriate if you need to know your parameters at the time of construction, you need all string generators to conform to a common interface (though there are ways around this), etc...

Comment: Yes, I really need this parameter (_length_) to be provided at the construction time, to reduce the complexity of code and have a straightforward implementation.

Comment: But why bundling them together in the interface? I think it's OK to have all of creation methods in one concrete factory, but why declare all of them in the interface? I think in my case, having an interface revealing a creation method for `FixedLengthStringGenerator` suffices.

Comment: Sure - depending on your needs/requirements, it may/may not be better to have a separate factory interface per type of string generator that you may need to create.  I think it comes down to how it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** 
So then the design goes like this.

Though One should avoid injecting parameters in constructor as much possible. 
Now, We can inject the dependencies through any standard DI container i.e Unity, AutoFac, Ninject

```
interface IStringGenerator
{
    string GenerateNext();
}
class FixStringGenerator:IStringGenerator
{
  public FixStringGenerator(int length)
  {
   ...
  }
  public string GenerateNext()
  {
      ///logic
  }
...
}
```

And for the MinMax string generator class as below injecting FixStringGenerator

```
class MinMaxStringGenerator:IStringGenerator
{
    ....
     IStringGenerator _fixStringGenerator;
     public MinMaxStringGenerator(int minLength,int maxLength, IStringGenerator fixStringGenerator)
     {
        _fixStringGenerator=fixStringGenerator;
     }
    string GenerateNext()
    {
     /// do the things with fix generator "_fixStringGenerator"
    }
    ....
 }
```

@Mostafa,The dependency injection needs to register both the implementations by instances so that it can create respective instances. [HOW TO DI named instance with constructor injection](http://sharpfellows.com/post/Unity-IoC-Container-)

More on DI [another link](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/register-and-resolve-in-unity-container)

Comment: This _Fixed string generator_, works like an _Enumerator_. It starts with an initial string. Then keeps track of current generated string and based on that, the next string will be generated. If I don't restrict my class to a fixed length (passing `length` through constructor), I have to keep track of current string for each length, which unnecessarily adds complexity to code.

Comment: On the other hand, this class dependencies work with a fixed length too. So not keeping the length fixed, leads to creating different instances of those dependencies inside `GenerateFixString(int)` you mentioned.

Comment: And one last thing, by defining `IStringGenerator` I meant to have different implementations for different scenarios, here `FixedLengthStringGenerator` and `MinMaxLengthStringGenerator`. So it doesn't help to have classes not implementing my interface.